# How can generate code coverage for JUnittestng tests on Java Script code?

Tags: javascript, junit, testng

I've got a lot of JUnit/testng test code running against a Java Script implementation. I'd like to generate code coverage of these tests on Java Script code.

Traditional java coverage tools like Emma/clover are not generating coverage reports on the java script code.

Any information/tools that would help me achieve this goal would be highly appreciated!

Thanks
Manish

Comment: You'd need to clarify what you mean by *"JUnit/testng test code running against a Java Script implementation"*

Comment: Sorry. My bad. Just to clarify, all the product implementation code is in Java Script and Mojo and the test code is in JUnit/TestNG. Hope it clarifies.

Comment: No, not really - you're saying you're testing JavaScript using Java frameworks; you'd need to show some code before anyone is able to help you out as it's a very unusual approach.

Comment: These are all selenium functional tests that would create browser objects and navigate across something like this... Browser browser = new Browser();
N2 n2 = new N2();
Abc abc = new Abc();

browser.launchBrowser("firefox");
Thread.sleep(6000);
  
Functional automated tests that run against Javascript/Mojo code base.

Comment: Can someone provide some solution please? Let me know if any of you need any more information.

Comment: The reason there's no help is most likely that JUnit and TestNG don't seem to be relevant to your problem; there are 256 results for "selenium coverage" - did you try looking for that?

Comment: Yeah. I did search through that method. Did not receive any relevant information as most of the data is not around javascript applications.